# Can we download the Autodesk Forge Viewer scripts for offline use?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it legal/possible to download the Autodesk Forge Viewer scripts and their dependencies to be provided on a local server for offline use?
For example: a website hosted on an internal network without internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Autodesk Viewer EULA prohibits you from copying the Viewer code on your server. See the copyright notice below, pay attention to the last few lines.

If you really need to copy the Viewer source code on your own machine/server, you need to contact Autodesk to get their written consent before proceeding. Please contact forge.help@autodesk.com and explain in details why you need that exception. Your case sounds legitimate, but they will need a bit more details, so engage the discussion there.

```js
/*!
 * LMV v7.39.1
 * 
 * Copyright 2021 Autodesk, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * This computer source code and related instructions and comments are the
 * unpublished confidential and proprietary information of Autodesk, Inc.
 * and are protected under Federal copyright and state trade secret law.
 * They may not be disclosed to, copied or used by any third party without
 * the prior written consent of Autodesk, Inc.
 * 
 * Autodesk Forge Viewer Usage Limitations:
 * 
 * The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by
 * Autodesk Forge services. The Autodesk Forge Viewer JavaScript must be
 * delivered from an Autodesk hosted URL.
 */
```

Comment: You allow pdfs to be uploaded locally to the viewer now. Does that violate the part that says "The Autodesk Forge viewer can only be used to view files generated by
 Autodesk Forge services."

Comment: gltf, and pdf can be loaded native or translated - if loaded native they won't participate the Viewer features, and only be served as WEB content. To be honest, if that is the only thing you load in the Forge Viewer, you should better use something else. The fact the viewer can load them native is to add more content to overlay a translated scene.

Comment: Oh yeah that is what I'm using it for, was just curious of the copyright. I use it to draw on vector pdfs and extract measurements etc.